# Find maximum number of arrays whose sum is less than a given array

Tags: algorithm

Given an array x of length n, and a set of arrays S such that each array in S has length n, find a maximal size set of arrays G in S such that for all 1 <= i <= n, x[i] >= sum(g[i]) for all g in G.

e.x. if x = [3, 3] and S = {[3, 0], [1, 1], [2, 1]}, then the best set is {[1, 1], [2, 1]} because the sum is [3, 2] and the element at each index is less than the corresponding element  in x. {[3, 0], [1, 1]} does not work because the sum is [4, 1], and 4 > x[0] = 3.

Is there an algorithm whose run time is polynomial in n and |S|?

Background/Context:
This question arose from a question on scrabble. Given a list of tiles, and a word, can you form the word with the tiles? I extended it to given a list of tiles, and a list of words, what is the maximum number of words in the list that can be formed from the tiles?

Comment: This is [multi-dimensional knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Multiple_constraints). It allows a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm only for fixed `n`.

Comment: The number of partitions of 9 (or whatever the number of owned tiles is) isn't that much. I'd go with brute-force.

Comment: Also see [liv.ac.uk COMP202](http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~ped/teachadmin/COMP202/annotated_np.html)'s NP-complete item 43 (Garey and Johnson's SP10) that may be equivalent

Answer (score 3):

This is [multi-dimensional knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knapsack_problems#Multiple_constraints).

To prove that there is no algorithm, polynomial-time in both `n` and `|S|` (or to prove that this is a [Strongly NP-hard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_NP-complete)), simplify this problem, allowing only values `1` for array `x` and values `0` or `1` for arrays `S`. After this simplification we get exactly the optimization version of [Set packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing), which is a classical NP-complete problem.

Relation to set packing problem suggests that there is also no good approximation algorithm.

This leaves pretty limited choice of algorithms:

1. [Branch-and-bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).
2. [Integer linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_linear_program#Integer_unknowns).
3. [Metaheuristic algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) like [Simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) or [Tabu search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taboo_search).